# Prove that $\exp(A+B)=\exp(A)\exp(B)$ iff $[A,B] = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have searched throughout the forum and online as well, and I got that with condition of $[A,B]=0$, $e^{(A+B)t}=e^{At}e^{Bt}$.

Now the question is, to show for any matrices $A$ and $B$, it is true that $e^{(A+B)t}=e^{At}e^{Bt}$ for all t if and only if $[A,B]=0$

Well, I asked my professor and he told me to show what if $AB \neq BA$, and I really have no idea how to condense those massive equations....

The reason why is that $[A,B]=0$ is not a condition given in this question and I'm confused.

Comment: Try comparing the coefficients of $t^n$ in the power-series of both sides of the equation. This should give something like $(A+B)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k} A^kB^{n-k}$ for all $n$. Then consider $n=2$.

Comment: I thought about that in that way, and when n goes up even to 3, it becomes something weird...and weirder and weirder.

Comment: You only need to consider $n=2$ (not prove this in general). Multiply out the power-series to $O(t^2)$ for $e^{At}e^{Bt}$ and compare with the left hand side.

Comment: So it's saying that for $n=2$ on both sides the coefficients must be the same and ignore the other terms?

Comment: Yes. Because if the coefficient of the $t^2$ term does not match then the two sides of the equation cannot be equal. btw this for proving that $e^{(A+B)t} = e^{At}e^{Bt} \implies [A,B] = 0$. For the other way around you need to consider all terms.

Comment: I see...Thank you! It seems that I was struggling on trying to prove all terms before. I actually get the other way, that's more straight forward to be honest, by comparing term by term

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show $e^{(A+B)t} = e^{At}e^{Bt}$ for all $t$ $\implies [A,B] = 0$ compare the coefficient of $t^2$ in the power-series expansion of both sides of the equation. We have
$$e^{(A+B)t} = 1+ (A+B)t + \color{red}{\frac{(A+B)^2}{2!} t^2} + \ldots$$

and

$$e^{At}e^{Bt} = \left(1+At + \frac{A^2}{2!}t^2+\ldots\right)\left(1+Bt + \frac{B^2}{2!}t^2+\ldots\right) \\= 1 + (A+B)t + \color{red}{\frac{A^2 + 2AB + B^2}{2!}t^2} + \ldots$$

Comparing the two expressions above gives us $$(A+B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2 \implies AB = BA$$

---

Comparing the general $t^n$-term in the power-series expansion gives us the equation $(A+B)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}A^kB^{n-k}$ which is just the binomial theorem which holds for matrices given that $[A,B] = 0$. This gives a proof of the other direction: $[A,B] = 0 \implies e^{(A+B)t} = e^{At}e^{Bt}$.

Comment: Also voted this positively and is among my favorites.